# Deploying uniswap v3 gets compiler errors

Tags: solidity, hardhat, uniswap

I am playing around with uniswap V3 on testnet and I am wondering, is it necessary to import all files and compile them to deploy the required contracts? I am getting a lot of compiler errors even though I specified them all in my hardhat config.

Config:

```
solidity: {
       compilers: [
          {
             version: '0.5.16',
             settings: {
                optimizer: {
                   enabled: true,
                   runs: 200,
                },
             },
          },
          {
             version: '0.8.0',
             settings: {
                optimizer: {
                   enabled: true,
                   runs: 200,
                },
             },
          },
          {
            version: '0.8.1',
            settings: {
               optimizer: {
                  enabled: true,
                  runs: 200,
               },
            },
         },
         {
            version: '0.6.6',
            settings: {
               optimizer: {
                  enabled: true,
                  runs: 200,
               },
            },
         },
         {
            version: '0.7.6',
            settings: {
               optimizer: {
                  enabled: true,
                  runs: 200,
               },
            },
         },
       ],
    },
```

Error:

```
Error HH606: The project cannot be compiled, see reasons below.

These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:

  * contracts/periphery/interfaces/external/IWETH9.sol (=0.7.6) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
  * contracts/periphery/interfaces/IERC20Metadata.sol (^0.7.0) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
  * contracts/Token.sol (=0.5.16) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol (^0.8.0)
  * contracts/periphery/base/ERC721Permit.sol (=0.7.6) imports @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol (^0.8.0) and @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Address.sol (^0.8.1)

These files depend on other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity:

  * contracts/periphery/SwapRouter.sol (=0.7.6) depends on @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0), @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0) and 19 other files. Use --verbose to see the full list.
  * contracts/periphery/V3Migrator.sol (=0.7.6) depends on @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol (^0.8.0), @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol (^0.8.0) and 22 other files. Use --verbose to see the full list.
  * contracts/periphery/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol (=0.7.6) depends on @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol (^0.8.0), @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol (^0.8.0) and 38 other files. Use --verbose to see the full list.
  * contracts/periphery/NonfungibleTokenPositionDescriptor.sol (=0.7.6) depends on @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol (^0.8.0), @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol (^0.8.0) and 13 other files. Use --verbose to see the full list.
  * contracts/periphery/libraries/PositionValue.sol (>=0.6.8 <0.8.0) depends on @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol (^0.8.0), @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Enumerable.sol (^0.8.0) and 6 other files. Use --verbose to see the full list.
  * contracts/periphery/examples/PairFlash.sol (=0.7.6) depends on @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0), @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0) and 2 other files. Use --verbose to see the full list.
  * contracts/periphery/base/LiquidityManagement.sol (=0.7.6) depends on @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0), @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol (^0.8.0) and 1 other file. Use --verbose to see the full list.

These files and its dependencies cannot be compiled with your config. This can happen because they have incompatible Solidity pragmas, or don't match any of your configured Solidity compilers.

  * contracts/periphery/libraries/NFTDescriptor.sol
  * contracts/periphery/base/PeripheryPaymentsWithFee.sol
  * contracts/periphery/base/PeripheryPayments.sol

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose

Read about compiler configuration at https://hardhat.org/config
```

When deploying uniswapV2 I did not run into these same issues while it was necessary to import a good chunk of files aswell. Is that because solidity 0.5 and 0.6 are more compatible?

Answer (score 1):

You have contracts with different solidity compiler versions and specified a bunch in your config.
However, just one compiler will be selected for compilation of a contract and its dependencies.
Hence, when you specify `pragma ^0.7.6` it means that you need at least compiler version `0.7.6`, but the selected compiler must be `<0.8.0`). Yet imported contracts are dependant on `^0.8.0` -> Error

One fix is to install openzeppelin at this version `0.7.0`:

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts@3.4.2-solc-0.7
```

Alternatively you could updated your uniswap contracts to `0.8.0`

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/tree/0.8/contracts

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/tree/0.8/contracts